# My page doesn't go further down. All the elements I put below go on existing elements

Tags: html

I coded the first part of my page but when I try to go further down the elements don't go below but on existing elements. The page has a huge picture all over it with some text, but I want to put other text below the picture not on it.

```css
.content {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}

.under {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 15%;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 80px;
}

.button {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/bmnuRawqdsI);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(44, 48, 56, 0.5);
  background: rgba(44, 48, 56, 0.5);
  color: rgba(44, 48, 56, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <h1>You Order. We Deliver.</h1>
      <p class="under">Get Coffee In 3 Easy Steps.</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <p class="button">Order A Coffee</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>How It Works.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <p>Order any coffee from one of our many brands.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post some code to show us what you tried?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Sorry can you also post the CSS as well?

Comment: Posted CSS as well.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? My first guess would be to remove `position: absolute;`

Comment: Your CSS shows you putting the background image on the `body`, which is pretty much everything. Put the background image on the element(s) you want the background image to show under.

Comment: Yeah, but when i do that it only puts it behind the, lets say, h1. I want it to go behind everything, to cover the whole screen.